# Why do I see strange symbols like '?2312?' instead of strings after running LEd?

Tags: led-editor

Why do I see strange symbols like '?2312?' instead of strings after running LEd like following image?

[image]

Comment: It looks like a problem with the localization, e.g., the installation was incomplete or the language of the operating system is not (yet) supported by LEd. If the language is not supported, then [this](http://www.latexeditor.org/tech_det.html) seems a starting point, if you want to contribute translations of the program strings to the LEd project.

Comment: The LEd project has not been supported or maintained since 2009.   I would recommend that you adopt an editor for LaTeX which is currently being maintained.   Here is a good starting link for assisting your choice http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/339/latex-editors-ides

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a bug in an unmaintained binary (and thus unfixable by answers on this site).